# Why laravel mailable doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, php-7

In my controller i have a function:

`Mail::send(new ShareByMail($post, $request->all()));`

It's ShareByMail:

```
public function __construct($entity, $request)
{
    $this->entity = $entity;
    $this->url = $this->entity->urls['main'];
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this
        ->to($this->request['to'])
        ->from('info@test', $this->request['from'])
        ->subject($this->entity->title ?: 'Share')
        ->view('mails.share_by_mail', [
            'entityTitle' => $this->entity->title ?: null,
            'entityText' => $this->entity instanceof Story ? $this->entity->subtitle : $this->entity->text,
            'entityImage' => $this->entity->image->url ?: null,
            'entityUrl' => config('app.frontend_url').'/'.$this->url,
            'additionalMessage' => $this->request['message'],
        ])
        ->onQueue('ShareByEmail');
}
```

All work perfect, except queue. I didn't start `queue:work`, but email already gets sent.

Comment: What do you have set in your .env file? If `QUEUE_DRIVER` equals sync, it will process immediately